# Pandas Extracting data from one column when corresponding Column is not NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
   col1     col2

0  Data 1   NaN
1  Data 2   C
2  Data 3   NaN
3  Data 4   R
4  Data 5   A
5  Data 6   NaN
```

I want to extract the data from `col1` where `col2` is `not NaN` and without `index`. Which is as below.

Output:

```
col1     col2

Data 2   C
Data 4   R
Data 5   A
```

How do I achieve it? Need help.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `df[pd.notnull(df['col2'])]` now I'm getting output, but with `index`. How can I eliminate `index'?

Comment: I got it by converting `to_string`. Thank you for the quick help.